# How to construct a quantum gate producing 1 if r divides x, 0 otherwise?

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

If you have two registers in the state $\frac{1}{2^{n/2}} \sum_{x = 0}^{2^{n/2} - 1} |x\rangle |0\rangle$, how could you construct a gate that produces a superposition of states $|x\rangle|1\rangle$ when some integer $r$ divides $x$, and $|x\rangle|0\rangle$ otherwise, for each input?

I.e. a unitary quantum gate that replicates the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } r \text{ divides } x\\
0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Comment: Do you mean for the second to be $r|x$ cast to 0 or 1. X is being summed over, not a free variable.

Comment: Yes, second register cast to a superposition of states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, based on whether the first register is a multiple of $r$. First register is an equal superposition of all states.

Comment: @AHusain Ah, I see what you mean. Does it make more sense after the edit?

Comment: Also what is your gate set? Is $r$ arbitrary?

Comment: Just the standard single-bit quantum gates, H, Paulis, $\pi/8$, etc. I'm using Q#. And yes, $r$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Controlled gates as well, if that wasn't obvious. CNOT, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to do a long division to compute the remainder, toggle the target bit if there is a non-zero remainder, then uncompute the long division.

Here is an example $r=3$, $N < 16$ circuit [in Quirk](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22QFT4%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setA%22%2C%22arg%22%3A9%7D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22inputB4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3C%3DB%22%5D%2C%5B%22-%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setA%22%2C%22arg%22%3A3%7D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22inputB4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3C%3DB%22%5D%2C%5B%22-%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputB4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3C%3DB%22%5D%2C%5B%22-%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance4%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22%2B%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputB4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3C%3DB%22%5D%2C%5B%22%2B%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputB4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3C%3DB%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setA%22%2C%22arg%22%3A9%7D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22%2B%3DA4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputB4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3C%3DB%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance4%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%97%A6%22%5D%5D%7D):

[image: mod 3 != 0 circuit]

Note the displays on the right hand side, which show that conditioning on the output qubit (the bottom one) leaves only values divisible by 3 in the input register (the top 4 qubits).

The basic idea is to keep track of the maximum value $m$ that could possibly be in the input register $i$, then iteratively pick the largest $k$ such that $r^k \leq m$ and subtract $r^k$ out of $i$ if $i \geq r^k$. This reduces $m$ by $r^k$. Repeat this until $m < r$, then toggle your output bit if $i=0$. Then uncompute all the conditional subtractions to restore $i$.

A proper construction would not require $r$ subtractions for each value of $k$ as this one does, and a proper construction would expand the comparison and addition circuits into their full form, but I think this construction gets the right idea across.